# Error in POST with Webhook in Zapier

Tags: php, post, webhooks, zapier

I'm trying to create a POST with a Webhook  in Zapier to store data in DB. In the test it gives me

> Bargle. We hit an error creating a post. :-( Error: 
>   DNSHTTPConnectionPool(host='www.btktest.it', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /school_html/production/zap.php (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to www.btktest.it timed out. (connect timeout=39)'))

What could it be?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it seems to be random...
I have my endpoint unprotected and it can be reached by other apps like postman or other apis but zapier suddely throws this error and my api didn't log any attempts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Zapier is having a problem posting data to your custom webhook URL. Can you verify the URL can be reached?

If it *can* be reached, try using an external tool (like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)) to make the same request that Zapier does (same URL endpoint and POST data).